# windows 7 -> vs10 -> OpenCV *DesperateForHelp*

Tags: windows, visual-c++, opencv, header, include

Hey i have searched every where about this issue and i still cant find my answers. Here's the deal, I'm a beginner and for my semester project i need to use the OpenCV. During its installation I'm getting two problems:

1.) the property pages that I'm supposed to make and save for further
    use,i cant save them. The option is grayed out, i did everything
    written here:
    http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation

2.) the headers im including i.e

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

give errors,  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp': No such file or directory what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to adjust your "Additional Include Dirs", so that it points to

```
opencv/build/include
```